# from collections import defaultdict

Tags: python, dictionary, collections, defaultdict

why is it when I do not set **default value** of **defaultdict** to be zero *(int)*, my below program does not give me results:

```
>>> doc
'A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart. I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine. I am so happy'
>>> some = defaultdict()
>>> for i in doc.split():
...  some[i] = some[i]+1
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
KeyError: 'A'
>>> some
defaultdict(None, {})
>>> i
'A'
```

yet it works with a **default value**

```
>>> some = defaultdict(int)
>>> for i in doc.split():
...  some[i] = some[i]+1
...
>>> some
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'A': 1, 'wonderful': 1, 'serenity': 1, 'has': 1, 'taken': 1, 'possession': 1, 'of': 4, 'my': 2, 'entire': 1, 'soul,': 1, 'like': 2, 'these': 1, 'sweet': 1, 'mornings': 1, 'spring': 1, 'which': 2, 'I': 3, 'enjoy': 1, 'with': 1, 'whole': 1, 'heart.': 1, 'am': 2, 'alone,': 1, 'and': 1, 'feel': 1, 'the': 2, 'charm': 1, 'existence': 1, 'in': 1, 'this': 1, 'spot,': 1, 'was': 1, 'created': 1, 'for': 1, 'bliss': 1, 'souls': 1, 'mine.': 1, 'so': 1, 'happy': 1})
>>>
```

**Could you tell why does it work like thus?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation says:

> The first argument provides the initial value for the `default_factory`
>   attribute; it defaults to `None`. All remaining arguments are treated
>   the same as if they were passed to the dict constructor, including
>   keyword arguments.

Therefore, if you just write `defaultdict` without passing any value to the constructor, the default value is set to `None`
See the output:

```
some = defaultdict()
print(some)    # defaultdict(None, {})
```

And when the value is set to `None`, you can not execute: `some[i] = some[i]+1`.
Thus, you have to set the default value to `int` explicitly: `some = defaultdict(int)`